# How to programmatically determine if the class is a case class or a simple class?

Tags: class, scala

How to programmatically determine if the given class is a case class or a simple class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (2011), you can use reflection to find out if the class implements the interface `scala.Product`:

```
scala> def isCaseClass(o: AnyRef) = o.getClass.getInterfaces.find(_ == classOf[scala.Product]) != None
isCaseClass: (o: AnyRef)Boolean

scala> isCaseClass(Some(1))
res3: Boolean = true

scala> isCaseClass("")
res4: Boolean = false
```

This is just an approximation - you could go further and check if it has a `copy` method, if it implements `Serializable`, if it has a companion object with an appropriate `apply` or `unapply` method - in essence, check for all the things expected from a case class using reflection.

The scala reflection package coming in one of the next releases should make case class detection easier and more precise.

EDIT:

You can now do it using the new Scala Reflection library -- see other answer.

Comment: Thank you, axel22. This is a solution to my problem. I hope the developers will add this method of Scala as soon as possible. Сlass implements the interface scala.Product - this is a sufficient condition for it?

Comment: No, there is no sufficient condition to check this (afaik). You cannot check for the existence of a `case` modifier in the original code, only for the methods that get generated due to the `case` modifier. As I wrote above, the whole thing is just an approximation.

Answer (score 23):

Using new Scala reflection API:

```
scala> class B(v: Int)
defined class B

scala> case class A(v: Int)
defined class A

scala> def isCaseClassOrWhat_?(v: Any): Boolean = {
     |   import reflect.runtime.universe._
     |   val typeMirror = runtimeMirror(v.getClass.getClassLoader)
     |   val instanceMirror = typeMirror.reflect(v)
     |   val symbol = instanceMirror.symbol
     |   symbol.isCaseClass
     | }
isCaseClassOrWhat_$qmark: (v: Any)Boolean

scala> class CaseClassWannabe extends Product with Serializable {
     |   def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = ???
     |   def productArity: Int = ???
     |   def productElement(n: Int): Any = ???
     | }
defined class CaseClassWannabe

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?("abc")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(1)
res1: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(new B(123))
res2: Boolean = false

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(A(321))
res3: Boolean = true

scala> isCaseClassOrWhat_?(new CaseClassWannabe)
res4: Boolean = false
```

Comment: this is great.. but you need an instance of the class to detect this. can it be done with just the type information? after all the question was to detect if the `class` was a case class not the instance is from a case class or not..

Comment: You can reflect on a class too, eg with `typeMirror.classSymbol(clazz).isCaseClass`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean: Can I determine whether a class is a case class or a non-case class programmatically, the answer is no, but you can do an approximation. Case classes are just a compiler hack, they tell the compiler to create certain methods etc. In the final bytecode, there is no difference between normal classes and case classes.

From [How does a case class differ from a normal class?](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/258)

> 1. You can do pattern matching on it,
> 2. You can construct instances of these classes without using the new
>      keyword,
> 3. All constructor arguments are accessible from outside using
>      automatically generated accessor functions,
> 4. The toString method is automatically redefined to print the name
>      of the case class and all its arguments,
> 5. The equals method is automatically redefined to compare two
>      instances of the same case class structurally rather than by identity.
> 6. The hashCode method is automatically redefined to use the
>      hashCodes of constructor arguments.

So you can actually create a case class by just defining the correct methods & companion objects yourself.

For an idea as to how to find out if a class **could** be a case class, look at the answer from axel22.